apt-get update cannot find Ubuntu servers in Pakistan region
Pinging mirror.virtury.com [103.151.111.245] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

I am continuously checking this address is not online and due to unknown reasons, I couldn't get traffic from this site.
Pinging us.archive.ubuntu.com [91.189.91.82] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 91.189.91.82: bytes=32 time=192ms TTL=43
Reply from 91.189.91.82: bytes=32 time=192ms TTL=43
Reply from 91.189.91.82: bytes=32 time=193ms TTL=43

This is when the US region traffic is on but in the Pakistan region, this is happening. kindly help me out with this. I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 & Ubuntu 18.04.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.   Not all mirrors support ESM/Pro and releases that are EOSS which bionic now is

Maybe useful https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  (do note that includes releases in standard support; with 18.04 now in EOSS or EOL (depending on architecture) provided/supported now by Canonical)

Close voters: Question should not be closed because it is about 22.04 as well

This question is similar to: How can I select a mirror than the one apt-get chose for me?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm not sure what the point will be in keeping this open. There's nothing random users on the internet can do about something like this other than suggesting to use a different mirror.

This Server is simply down.
I tried a ping from Germany and got this result:

$ ping mirror.virtury.com ---
PING mirror.virtury.com (103.151.111.245)
56(84) bytes of data.
--- mirror.virtury.com ping statistics --- 13 packets transmitted,
0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12287ms

Possibly they are working right now on the Server and it is not connected to the Internet. So try it an other day or chose an other Server.
